# Android Multi-User behaviour: how to install application package for all users

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-source, multi-user

I'm exploring the [Android Multi-User](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user) behavior regarding the PackageManager.
I’m trying to understand how the Packages are installed in each User and how the installation in all users can be achieved.

Could not find a way to install a package for all users, only for the current user. Testing in Android 11 emulator (AOSP) with my sample application that installs packages using PackageInstaller.

What I'm able to test:

- Put my sample app as system app, so it will have the restricted permissions to install and remove packages and also it will be shown in every User
- Create new Users and switch between them
- [List all application packages that are installed for the current user](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstalledApplications(int))
- Using the my sample app, install package for the current user. I'm using the [PackageInstaller.Session](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.Session#commit(android.content.IntentSender)) to achieve this successfully.
- Install package X with User A, switch to User B and I couldn't see the package X in the applications, however I was able to install the same package X on User B
- Unable to install lower versions of the same package (same packagename). (Install package X, verCode=2 on User A, switch to User B and try to install package X, verCode=1). However I can install packages with vercode >=
- User B does not see what User A have installed
- With help of Android Studio (AS) Device Explorer, I'm able to find the installed packages metadata (apk) located here: /data/app/[some strange hash]/[packagename of the app]
- With help of AS device explorer I'm able to find the data folder for each package that is dedicated for each user: /data/user/[user id]/[packagename of the app]

As per my knowledge, and I'm only referring to what I've found in the official Android documentation, I couldn't find a way to programmatically install packages in all the Users. Also, I couldn't find a method to list all the packages installed in the device (not in current user, but in the device).

**Now that you know my status of investigation, maybe there is someone who can help me some official statement or a workaround.**

**1. Is there a way to (programmatically) list all the installed packages in the device, not dependent on current user?**

**2. Is there a way to (programmatically) install packages for all the users and not only the current user?**

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Comment: Also searching for a solution